# Testing python asyncio coroutine with pytest-asyncio plugin raises TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, python-asyncio

I am trying to test the following method with the pytest asyncio plugin:

```
class Controller(object):

    async def get_item(self, item_id):
        item = await self.item_collection.find_one({'item_id': item_id})
        return item
```

And I've written the following test:

```
class TestController(object):

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_get_item(self):

        controller = Controller()
        item = await controller.get_item('item-1')
        assert item.get('item_id') == 'item-1'
```

This test raises the following error:

```
   item = await self.item_collection.find_one({'item_id': item_id})
   TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression
```

If I remove the await in `item = await self.item_collection.find_one({'item_id': item_id})` the test passes, but how can I go about testing this method as it is?

Comment: Are you mocking `find_one`?

Comment: Hi @dirn, I am using the pytest-mongodb plugin with json fixtures, which in turn uses MongoMock. The mocked mongo collection works as expected, sorry I left that out.

Comment: It doesn’t look like MongoMock understands asyncio. It defines a collection that has regular methods, not coroutines. What driver are you using? Motor? You’ll probably need to either look for a library that can mock that or handle it yourself.

Comment: @dirn I just tested returning a simple coroutine and it works so you are correct, MongoMock is not understanding asyncio. I'll look into handling that bit, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, mongomock does not play well with asyncio. I created a package that should work with mongodb motor for asyncio calls: https://github.com/xzased/pytest-async-mongodb